# tcp port 12202 not opening on ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, iptables, firewall

I created an EC2 ubuntuu 12.04 instance. i have opened TCP 12202 port through security group console of AWS .But i am unable to open instance port . I tried below commands to open the port .

**sudo iptables -F

sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 0/0 -s 0/0 -p tcp  --dport 12202 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A INPUT -d 0/0 -s 0/0 -p tcp  --sport 12202 -j ACCEPT**

. but no result . when i check through **nmap**  . it says port 12202 closed . what would be the cause ?

Comment: Do you have something listening on that port?

Answer (score 3):

You have no program listening to port 12202. Start the service.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the port is opened for all or for specific Source IPs only in the AWS Security Group.
2. Then cross-check if you have the ports opened.
3. Try these commands:

> ```
> sudo lsof -i
> sudo netstat -tulpn
> ```

Also check the status of SELinux.

Hope this helps

Comment: Not worked even SElinux is disabled.

Comment: Could you stop IPtables and check if port is accessible

Comment: I stopped IPtables Still port is closed .

Comment: can u paste the SG entry of the paricular instance?

Comment: 0 - 65535 0.0.0.0/0 Delete    
22 (SSH) 0.0.0.0/0 Delete         This is the TCP port entries of SG for this instance .

Comment: @manjunath So ports open. can u paste output of 'sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 12202'

Comment: No results  from that command

Comment: That means that the port is not open in IPtables. Add the port again, restart IPtables and try this again.